# How to confirm about NO JWT-auth connection for gateway connection of Cloud IoT Core

Tags: google-cloud-platform, jwt, google-cloud-iot

I have problems about JWT authentication. Using devices can't use JWT for specification of devices. 
And then, I can connect to gateway on Google Console(Test environment) and use [sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/python-docs-samples/tree/master/iot/api-client/mqtt_example) code of Google.
***cloudiot_mqtt_example.py
*gateway_demo.py**

However, I don't know how to confirm NO JWT-auth.

I checked Stackdriver logging but I can't get logs for solving problem.
I can checked to send publishing data via gateway to devices and Cloud Pub/Sub. However, I need to know other method because using test environment can connect JWT and NO JWT.

I debugged source code above URL. This code is definitely via get_client.

```
def get_client(
~
client.username_pw_set(
            username='unused',
            password= create_jwt (
                    project_id, private_key_file, algorithm))
```

This create_jwt make token.

I think this source programs are using JWT authentication. Would you like to tell me how to check JWT authentication?

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn't recommend connecting without a JWT , but you can check the JWT by printing it out and going to JWT.io and see if it matches your project specifications.

If you can't connect using a JWT then you might be providing the wrong setup information or your private key is wrong so the authentication of the JWT is wrong.